# Soft keyboard issue in flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex

I am building a tablet application which contains a login form. I am using soft keyboard to enter credentials and I am doing 'stage.focus=null' to hide softkeyboard, after this if I open a popup it is coming in half of the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is you're trying to fix.  A screenshot and/or some code may help me understand better.

Comment: Thanks for you interest, I am unable to upload images as i am a new user can you give your email so that i can send you the screen shots.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to my problem, I resolved this after setting *resizeForSoftKeyboard* property to *SkinnablePopUpContainer*.

Thakns,
Gopi.

Comment: Be sure to select this as the correct answer for other users of the site.

Comment: What do you mean, 'set resizeForSoftKeyboard property to SkinnablePopUpContainer'? It can only be true or false..

Answer (score 0):

This post here gave me some hints http://forums.adobe.com/message/4068144 but didn't fix my problem. What finally worked for me was 'forcing' the keyboard to close by resetting the focus and deferring my state change until afterwards.

```
callLater(setFocus); // set focus to current view

callLater(function():void { /*.. my state change code ..*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

The way we fixed this problem was to fire our own deactivate event on our TextInput.

```
callLater(function():void {
    myTextInput.dispatchEvent(new SoftKeyboardEvent(SoftKeyboardEvent.SOFT_KEYBOARD_DEACTIVATE, true, false, null, "contentTriggered"));
});
```